# Setting in maximum entries, by default it shows only five entries

Tags: php, feedback, ebay-design-templates

I want to show ebay feedback on my website. By default is shows only five feedback, and I want maximum feedback.

In plugin customization I update data entries from five to hundred but it doesn't work

```
'feedback_limit'  => array(
        'name' => 'feedback_limit',
        'id' => 'feedback_limit',
        'tip' => 'This number determines how many feedback entries will be displayed.',
        'title' => 'Entries to Show (1-500)',
        'default' => '100',
        'input_processing' => array(
            'preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $param_value);'
        )           
    ),
```

I expect 100 to 200 entries but it displays only 5